# DataTable.GetChanges() is it possible to get rows by reference?

Tags: vb.net, datatable

```
Dim dtModifiedData As DataTable = dtMain.GetChanges(DataRowState.Modified)
```

As the definition of the function says, it does copy the rows after filtering it from the main table.

Is it possible to get them by reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes:

```
Dim modifiedRows = From row In dtMain.AsEnumerable()
                   Where row.RowState = DataRowState.Modified
```

If you need it in a `DataTable`, that's not possible because a `DataRow` always belongs to one `DataTable`. If you try to move it from one to another you'll get an exception. You need a method like [`ImportRow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.importrow(v=vs.100).aspx) which creates a new `DataRow` with the values from the source-row. For the same reason `CopyToDataTable` on above LINQ query will also create new `DataRows`.

Comment: Thank you, your solution is perfect to my question.
The main problem was that I'd like to do some check to modifiedRows, then set .SetColumnError to it. But since they are copied I set it for nothing. In that way, as you exaplained, I have the same problem.

Comment: @misiMe: i'm not sure if i understand your comment. You can use `SetColumnError` on the rows above. Just use a loop: `For Each row In modifiedRows row.SetColumnError(0, "ErroText")
        Next`